# Creating a template image dynamically for OSX menu bar

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm having trouble creating a template image for the OSX menu bar. As far as I can tell, it has to be a PDF image. To that end, I have:

```
var pageRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(10), CGFloat(barHeight))
let pdfData: NSMutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)
let pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(pdfData as CFMutableDataRef)
let pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(pdfConsumer, &pageRect, nil)
```

Then I draw into the PDF:

```
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil)
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 1, 0, 0, 1)
CGContextFillRect (pdfContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ))
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext)
```

Then I try to create an NSImage:

```
let image = NSImage(data: pdfData)
```

And add it to the status item's image property:

```
button.image = image
```

However, this just isn't working. I have tried saving the image to disk and opening it, but get the message that the image is corrupted, so I suspect the error is in converting the pdfData into an NSImage, though I'm not totally confident of that. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A template image does **not** have to be a PDF. To make an instance of `NSImage` a template image, simply set its `template` property to true.

No matter the nature of the image (bitmap, PDF, whatever), the system will only make use of its alpha channel when it's a template image. The color channels are ignored.

The system will automatically mark an image loaded from a file as a template image if its filename-minus-extension ends with "Template". So, for example, fooTemplate.png or barTemplate.pdf.